# Triggerio: Test on device fails at 49%

Tags: trigger.io

I've setup my certificates correctly and it's not that. While trigger is copying everything to the device (I've tried one iPhone 4 with 5.1.1 AND an iPhone 4 with iOS6 beta 4) and it fails at 49%.

Line in console log: `[ 49%] Copying PATH/development/ios/device-ios.app//tabs_modalWebViewController.nib to device`

Going back in the console log, I find the following info if it helps any:
`[ERROR] Failed when running /Users/joshmbrown/forge-workspace/fi-monuments/.lib/fruitstrap`
`ShellError: Failed when running PATH/.lib/fruitstrap`

Any suggestions?

I've reinstalled Xcode and the proper command line utilities. I've also performed an `xcode-select` in the terminal. What else?

Comment: Hey, just checking - have you installed the Xcode command line utilities (in Preferences > Downloads)?

Comment: As the post says, I've reinstalled Xcode and the proper command line utilities. ;)

Comment: For anyone else having problems copying iOS apps to devices, take a look at the _device's_ console - Xcode ↠ Window ↠ Organizer ↠ Console (in the left sidebar).